# Best way to notify a component of a global event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a data grid component where the user can select multiple rows. The component manages the currently selected rows as part of its state:

```
var Datagrid = React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      selection: []
    }
  },

  handleRowClick(id, event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
      this.setState({ selection.concat([id]) });
    }
  },

  render() {
    return
      <div>
        {this.props.data.map( rowdata => <Row data={rowdata}> )}
      </div>
    ;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Datagrid data={data}>, document.querySelector('#grid1'))
```

This works and encapsulates the (in reality rather complicated) selection logic nicely.

But now I want this component to deselect all rows when the page body is clicked.

It seems rather cumbersome to have the global store manage the selections of all data grids, just to be able to deselect them. I like the fact that the selection logic is encapsulated in the component, I just want to notify it of that global event.

I had the idea of passing a callback as a prop that resets itself, but that seems very convoluted:

```
var notification = false;

body.onclick = function () {

  notification = function() { notification = false; } // Marks a pending notification

  ReactDOM.render(<Datagrid data={data} notification={notification}>, document.querySelector('#grid1'))

}

var Datagrid = React.createClass({
  ...

  render() {

    if (this.props.notification) {
      this.setState({ selection: [] });
      this.props.notification(); // Reset the notification
    }

    ...
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Datagrid data={data} notification={notification}>, document.querySelector('#grid1'))
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the correct way to handle this case is setup the listener when the component mounts and then remove it when it unmounts like so:

```
var Datagrid = React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      selection: []
    }
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', this.handleClear);
  },

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClear);
  },

  handleClear() {
    this.setState({ selection: []});
  },

  handleRowClick(id, event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
      this.setState({ selection.concat([id]) });
    }
  },

  render() {
    return
      <div>
        {this.props.data.map( rowdata => <Row data={rowdata}> )}
      </div>
    ;
  }
});
```